# Easier way to cut tiles than using tile cutter?

Tags: tile

I want to cut 4x8" tiles down the middle (for 2 4"x4" tiles), so I bought two versions of [this tile cutting machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dkzS.png) (the pic is from Home Depot and the other one I bought is from Amazon).

They cut the tile most of the time but it's difficult and cumbersome. The cuts aren't really clean. I know these machines are relatively cheap, but this is for a project I'm working on and don't want to spend alot on a machine.

Is there an easier way of cutting tile?

Comment: Buy, rent, or borrow a wet bridge saw.

Comment: you're unlikely to find anything faster than these.  what do you mean by "cumbersome"?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to purchase or rent a tile saw.  They come in smaller versions so you don't need the commercial type on wheels that the tile contractors have.

The possibilities are [7 inch table top](https://www.harborfreight.com/48-amp-7-in-table-top-wet-cut-tile-saw-69231.html?ccdenc=eyJjb2RlIjoiNzA0ODg1NjAiLCJza3UiOiI2OTIzMSIsImlzIjoiNjIuOTkifQ%3D%3D&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=19231709246&campaignid=19231709246&utm_content=145174694300&adsetid=145174694300&product=69231&store=144&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiA44OtBhAOEiwAj4gpOdK-P_DtTipzNziyoR0M9M_GssY4PEKXKByfL4VuEM-UsRMUmo2LmhoCb44QAvD_BwE), or [4 inch hand held](https://www.harborfreight.com/7-amp-4-in-handheld-dry-cut-tile-saw-62296.html?ccdenc=eyJjb2RlIjoiNzA0ODQ5ODYiLCJza3UiOiI2MjI5NiIsImlzIjoiMzMuOTkifQ%3D%3D&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=19231709222&campaignid=19231709222&utm_content=141253633421&adsetid=141253633421&product=62296&store=144&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiA44OtBhAOEiwAj4gpOQRhWMa-u_yPrqVwQhzap9k2u8OevOkOQ2nc8ZnCPEgbCi7FWvVbWRoC4UMQAvD_BwE).

Something to remember is to get a nice clean cut, your need a good diamond blade.  The cheaper saws often have low quality blades and even when new the cuts are not good.

Comment: Beg, buy, borrow or steal anything that says it cuts tile that isn't one of those damn things.

Comment: Don't forget that saws have a kerf, though, so you probably don't want to mix & match tiles from the unpowered cutter and the saw.